# Import react component using script tag

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react, and you like to know if there is a way to import a react component using `<script>` tag.

example:
`<script src="addres/to/my.js"></script>`

the reason to do that is that the page I'm importing is just a plain HTML.

I'm looking to something like this: `https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html`
but with a remote js.

Another question, how I generate this remote `js` with the dependencies? or that is not even possible?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: How do you intend to use a component "imported" this way?

Comment: In react page example is used by "replacing" a `div`, was thinking if possible, to do the same